# In Chicken Scheme how can I require files when writing a script

Tags: chicken-scheme

I'm using the BDD library missbehave for Chicken Scheme to write some scripts.

I currently have a single file containing my specs and my code that I run with `behave`. This works as expected. Running my tests to verify the code.

I know that when using the `csc` compiler I can define units and link files using the following syntax

```
# foo.scm
(define (uses bar))

# bar.scm
(define (unit bar))
```

and when both files are compiled and linked this will work.

I can't find a way of acheiving something similar for a script that is run using the `csi` interpreter. Is there a way to do this?

An analogous concept would be `require_relative` in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(load "relative_file.scm")
```

This works in interpreted code only. I also just found the `inclub` egg which looks like it works both in interpreted and compiled code.